# showing compactness for a subset of a function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Our professor told us the following in lecture: Let $X_A:=\{f\colon A\to\mathbb R|f(A) \textrm{ is bounded}\}$ and $\alpha(f,g):=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)| \;|x\in A\}$. Given $\beta\colon A\to\mathbb R, f(a)=0$ for all $a\in A$, when is $\overline{B_1(\beta)}:=\{g\in X_A:\alpha(\beta,g)\leq 1\}\subset X_A$ compact?

He told that for finite sets $A$ the neighborhood is compact but for countable and uncountable sets not but he didn't mention why.

So my question is how can you show this formaly? I thougt about using sequential compactness, so let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\overline {B_1(\beta)}$. Then all elements of the sequence are formed of $a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n$ ($A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$) and so there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ converging to a point $a_i\in A$ and so it's compact, right?
How can you get the other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is finite, and let $N$ be its cardinality. Then $X_A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^N$ endowed with the usual topology and $\overline{B_1(\beta))}$ is $[-1,1]^N$, a compact set.

Assume that $A$ is infinite. It contains $\{x_n,n\in\mathbb N\}$, a countable collection of disjoint points. Define $g_n$ by $g_n(x_n)=1$ and $g_n(x)=1$ if $x\neq x_n$. Then $g_n\in \overline{B_1(\beta)}$ and $\alpha(g_m,g_n)=1$ if $m\neq n$. So we cannot extract a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ contains a infinite countable subset $\{a_1 ,a_2 ,...\} .$ Then the functions $$ f_i (\sigma ) =\begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ for } \sigma = a_i \\ 0 \mbox{ for } \sigma \neq a_i \end{cases}$$ are elements of $B_1 (\beta ) $ and $\alpha (f_i , f_j ) =1$ for $i\neq j .$ So the set $B_1 (\beta ) $ could not be compact .